# Retrieve array of only none empty form field

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have an array of different items that are coming from a form and i would like to pull the keys of the none empty fields. I know that i can use the `array_keys()` function, but that would give me all of the keys (empty and not empty). Is there a function for the fields that are not empty or how can i do this?

```
$array=$_POST;
```

I need to get the not empty fields from `$array`.

Comment: `$array = array_filter($_POST)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to filter the array using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function

```
$array = array_filter($_POST)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$my = ("0"=>" ","1"=>"5","2"=>"6","3"=>" ");   

foreach ($my as $key => $value) {
    if (is_null($value)) unset($my[$key]);
}

foreach ($my as $key => $value) {
    echo   $key . ':' . $value . '<br>';
}

**output
1:5
2:6** 

You can use array_filter function as well for trimming empty elements
```